# Excel Macro With template, want to use it many different reports but em stuck on it

Tags: vba, excel

I am using below mention macro with template for formatted my daily reports,
but the issue is, its just working on 1 specific name sheet(Archroma Pakistan Ltd.xls), i want to use it for 35 more reports, for example:

"Al-Fazal Associates (Pvt) Ltd."
"Capital Assets Leasing Corporation Limited"
"Carvan Carriage Company (Chevron 425)"

```
Sub Macro17()
    '
    ' Macro17 Macro
    ' loc
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O
    '
    Columns("F:R").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:K").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
    'Windows("UEPL - Copy.xls").Activate
    Windows("**Archroma Pakistan Ltd.xls**").Activate
    Range("A3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add Template:= "\\172.16.4.241\Analysis\NR Status11.xltm"
    'Windows("NR Status11").Activate
    Windows("NR Status111").Activate
    Range("A14").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A15").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Rows("24:24").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 17
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 19
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 22
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 26
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 29
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 31
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 35
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 38
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 43
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 48
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 53
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 59
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 67
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 76
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 85
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 99
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 112
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 124
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 136
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 148
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 160
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 171
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 181
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 189
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 198
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 204
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 211
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 216
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 218
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Rows("24:231").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A21").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A2:B2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you know whether mistake is.

```
Windows("**Archroma Pakistan Ltd.xls**").Activate
```

So you need to change that name to the relevant sheet name if you need to work for others as well. Hope all the reports are in the same format.

Comment: Windows("Archroma Pakistan Ltd.xls").Activate

Comment: Windows("Al-Fazal Associates (Pvt) Ltd.").Activate

Comment: i am using this format "Windows("Archroma Pakistan Ltd.xls").Activate" but i  want to run this same macro on many sheets, without changes in macro ,

Comment: i want to apply this macro on all workbooks and want to save on them location, but i think **loop** or **Variable** is required :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer then.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.select
```

instead the above one